# Logic Pro X: When pasting notes in a region, how to prevent resizing?

Tags: logic-pro

In LPX, if I have a region that is 4 bars long and I copy notes from another region that spans 2 bars into this one, it will be resized to the length that matches my paste.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Wait, when you paste the notes the destination region resizes to 2 bars or the pasted notes are stretched out across 4 bars? Also, is the destination region blank before you paste into it, or does it already have notes?

Comment: Usually I set a region of the length I will use, so the region is empty and I'm just pasting a set of notes I copied from another region; the notes don't get stretched, but the region's end gets moved to the last note.

Comment: This doesn't tell you how to prevent it (I hope there's a way), but you can restretch the region back to the size you want after pasting, correct?

Comment: yes, I can stretch it back; it's not a blocking issue, more like an annoyance